# Mapping a 3D parametric surface color with something other than z

Tags: javascript, 3d, plotly

I am now using plotly.js to make 3D parametric surfaces appear in a web page.

An example of such surface can be found here: https://plot.ly/~JeremyGuillon/79/parametric-surface/

Plotly takes x, y and z as 2-dimensional arrays and assume that the color of the surface should be mapped with the value of z at each point.

Does anyone know a way of mapping the color with the value of r = x^2+y^2+z^2, instead of the default?